# ui-grid customs cell template remains in edit mode after focus loss

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I try to set simple custom template to cell but I lose some behaviour like focus.

I use `'ui.grid.cellNav'` and relevant column configured like:

```
    {
      name: 'name', 
      displayName: 'Name (editable)', 
      width: '30%',
      enableFocusedCellEdit: true,
     editableCellTemplate: 'custom_edit.html'
    },
```

My template looks like:

```
<div class="grid-tooltip"
     tooltip="{{ row.entity.description }}" 
     tooltip-placement="right"
     tooltip-append-to-body="true">
             <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
                   <input type="text"
                       ng-model="row.entity.description">
              </div>
 </div>
```

This is a demo I play with: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/upyEqzuDbrPA2TM6PCtO?p=preview) - Try to edit `Name(Editable)` column

When I edit cell in second column and press `Enter` - nothing happens or when I click on other cell, or move up/down with keyboard the older cell left editable. Its not the same behaviour like 3d column `Name(default)`

I tried to set `ng-model="COL_FIELD"` but get error:

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'grid.getCellValue(row, col)' is non-assignable.
>
> Element: `<input ng-model="grid.getCellValue(row, col)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">`

Please help,

I'm sure I miss something simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update input field in template

```
<input type="text" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">
```